# How do I get base-space transform from CGContext?

Tags: transform, core-graphics, cgcontext

The offset for `CGContext.setShadow` has to be specified in base-space:

> offset - Specifies a translation in base-space.

(from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext/1455205-setshadow)

**What is this "base-space"?**

Semi related docs have this explanation:

> - The drawing (user) coordinate system. This coordinate system is used when you issue drawing commands.
> - The view coordinate system (base space). This coordinate system is a fixed coordinate system relative to the view.
> - The (physical) device coordinate system. This coordinate system represents pixels on the physical screen.

(from: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html)

This makes sense. However, **how do I get the transform of this base-space?** There is `CGContext.userSpaceToDeviceSpaceTransform` but it seems to be transform from user->physical. How do I get from user->base or base->physical?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the base-space is equivalent to when the user-space has an identity transform matrix. In [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html), figure 1-1, the show the base-space have the origin in the upper-left, and an identity matrix of one (the indicated pixel of (3, 5) is 3 to the right, 5 down, as expected).

Thus, the shadow offset is in *untransformed* units. This is probably convenient for you, as you probably want the shadow offset to be the same, regardless of what the scale factor is. (If you scale a piece of vector clip art in a PowerPoint presentation, you want the shadow to be offset the same no matter how big you expand the clip art.)

Comment: That's roughly the interpretation that I ended up with too. I'm not sure what you mean by "untransformed" as base->physical can contain scaling and flipping on Y. Anyway, I just calll `CGContext.userSpaceToDeviceSpaceTransform` before applying any transforms and that seems to give me base->physical. I just find it a bit odd that there is no function for this once some transform is applied.

Comment: @PauliusLiekis I'm thinking of "base-space" and basically what you get if you draw into the View without making any transformations. There may be transformations underneath the hood, but from the caller's perspective the transform is an identity matrix.